# Symfony - How can I omit the first item in a twig template's loop?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to display news without first one. How I can achieve this?

Here is code I have to change:

```
<div class="home-box-news carousel-news slide home-box-shadow" id="news" style="clear: both;">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators news-box">

    {% for i in 0..news|length-1 %}
        {% if loop.index is not divisibleby (2) %}
            <li data-target="#news" data-slide-to="{{ i / 2 }}" {% if loop.first %}class="active"{% endif %}></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for item in news %}
        {% if loop.index is not divisibleby (2) %}
            <div class="item{% if loop.first %} active{% endif %}">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
        {% endif %}
            <h3><a href="{{ path('home_news_index') }}">{{ item.name }}</a></h3>
            <p class="date">{{ item.createdAt|date('d.m.Y, G:i') }}</p>
            <p {% if loop.index is divisibleby (2) %}style="border-bottom: 0;" {% endif %}>{{ item.content[:110]|nl2br }}{% if item.content|length > 110 %}... <a class="more" href="{{ path('home_news_index') }}">czytaj dalej</a>{% endif %}</p>
        {% if loop.index is divisibleby (2) or loop.last %}
            </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `|slice` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this in your loop to omit first news

```
{% if loop.index0 > 0 %}
 {# display your news #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Be verbose: `{% if not loop.first %}`

Answer (score 14):

There is more concise version of what Robert suggested:

```
{% for item in news[1:] %}
```

Comment: You can send your very short answer as a comment.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter which works like array_slice() function in PHP.

```
{% for item in news[1, news.length -1 ] %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is another answer which may/may not be cleaner/simpler/w/e - don't pass the row to Twig in the first place.

Comment: This is the best answer. Don't write hacks, fix your sh**.

Comment: I don't know about it being the best answer, I suppose it depends on the context...maybe you need that row elsewhere for example...